# Route message based on Tag Value - Apache Camel

Tags: spring, jms, apache-camel

I am trying to learn Apache Camel Routes. For a basic example, I would like to know how to route based on values in an XML tag. For example, if we have 3 xml files with parent tags:

```
<item type="n1" />
<item type="n2" />
<item type="n3" />
```

I want to route these 3 into 3 different pipes...

so here is my idea (in Spring):

```
<route id="NormalizeMessageData">

<from uri="jms:incomingOrders" />
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />

<choice>
<when>
  <simple>${body} contains '?xml'</simple> <!-- to make sure its xml file only -->
  *
  *
  *
  <unmarshal>
    <jaxb contextPath="org.fusesource.camel" />
  </unmarshal>
  <to uri="jms:orders" />
</when>
</choice>
```

see the stars (*), this is where we need to put some checking. But how?

Comment: Have a look at the [xpath component](http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Camel xpath documentation linked above for all the details, but you should just need something like:

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <xpath>/item/@type = 'n1'</xpath>
        ...
    </when>
</choice>
```

Comment: hmm. How about `<xpath>//item[@type='n1']</xpath>`? will this also work?